# MySQL maximum character length storage

Tags: mysql, sql, types, sqldatatypes

How would I go about creating a column with the max length as the condition? I am using PHPMyAdmin. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want it to have the maximum amount of values possible.

Comment: I have changed the title of your question. If you find it's missing a point you've stated, please edit the title appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention PHPMyAdmin as your tool I assume that your database engine is MySQL.

String types in MySQL that have the largest storage capacity are `LONGBLOB` and `LONGTEXT`. They both require `L + 4 bytes` of storage, where `L < 2^32`.

> *L* represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.
>
> *4 bytes* are needed to store the length of the value

References:

- [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html)
- [The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)